# What's the Vim equivalent of Emacs's other-window command?

Tags: key-bindings, split

What's the Vim equivalent of Emacs's [other-window](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Window.html) command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<C-w>w` cycles through windows in a similar manner.